# Change color of Vuetify Timeline line

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, timeline

I need to change the color of the [Vuetify Timeline](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/timelines) line. Currently it's grey, how to change it to red?

```
    <template>
  <v-timeline>
    <v-timeline-item>timeline item</v-timeline-item>
    <v-timeline-item class="text-right">timeline item</v-timeline-item>
    <v-timeline-item>timeline item</v-timeline-item>
  </v-timeline>
</template>
```

Comment: You need to edit CSS: ```.v-timeline:before { background-color: red; }```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply below css. Depend on theme you can change `.theme--light`.

```
.theme--light.v-timeline:before {
    background: red;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sumitpatel/pen/rNBKJRL)